# Cannot use public modifier on PHP class

Tags: php, oop, access-modifiers

I have very strong basic in Java, and when comes to PHP I got some problem with the OOP.

Please take a look at this two classes below:

**Contacts.php**

```
<?php 

    public class Contacts {

    }
?>
```

**UnitTest.php**

```
<?php

    require_once 'PHPUnit/Framework.php';
    include 'Contacts.php';

    class UnitTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

        public function testRead() {
            $temp = new Contacts();
        }
    }
?>
```

When I trying to test the `UnitTest.php` using `phpunit` I got this error message:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_PUBLIC in
    /home/crazenezz/Projects/PHP/Demo/Class/Contacts.php on line 3
```

And after trial and error I remove the `public` modifier of `Contacts` class, and the test become success without error.

**Contacts.php** *(After remove the `public` modifier)*

```
<?php 

    class Contacts {

    }
?>
```

**Can anyone explain why in PHP I cannot use the `public` as modifier of a `class`?**

Comment: That wouldn't even make sense in your case, because you're not in a namespace.

Comment: Don't know why somebody downvoted the question as it is perfectly valid. upvoted it.

Comment: @Bgi: What do you mean by `not in a namespace`?

Comment: @Crazenezz He means that `public` as opposed to what... `private`? In that case, private *to what*? The only thing that comes to mind is *private/public* to the namespace. But PHP does not have visibility modifiers for namespaces.

Comment: @Crazenezz deceze explains it better than I do ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because all classes are public in PHP. There's no such thing as a "private class".

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you only use the public modifier in front of variables and functions. 
In Java you can use the public modifier infront of a class, constructor, method, variables or interfaces. Why? because the languages are different. If you need notes on it to remind yourself I wrote something here explaining the difference between PHP modifiers and Java modifiers, as I too learned Java way before PHP. http://www.siteconsortium.com/h/D0000G.php